# Cannot view source of certain tag wiki revisions

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, revisions-list, view-source

When I click **view source** on a some old revisions of tag wikis, I get a 404. This happens on both wikis I can edit and those I can't.

For example:

- [Revision 3](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/c6bd9b29-f60f-47df-a6b9-ebd90a4a2b61/view-source) of the [webapp-rec wiki](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/6290/revisions).
- [Revision 14](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/cdb4a51e-89e2-4974-8bb3-ec0f59c1649f/view-source) of the [java wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607018/revisions).
- [Revision 6](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/a7565d4c-bd01-4487-b40d-153ea8652588/view-source) of the [c# wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607007/revisions).

Comment: part fixed, ill deploy a migration tomorrow that wipes out these revisions.

Answer (score 2):

Yerp ... will be sorting this out, I am going to split out the excerpt into its own post

Completed the fix in dev will be deployed later today.